# Ant Bulk Search and Replace

Tags: ant, nant

I have a properties file in which the keys represent strings in source code files that I would like to search for, and the values represent the replacement string that I would like to replace the strings with (see below for an example).

I would like to perform these replacements over a set of files during my Ant build, however I cant seem to figure out how to perform this operation.  A simple replace is easy using the Ant replacement task, but I can't determine if there is a way using Ant tasks to perform this bulk search and replace using a properties file to indicate what to search and replace.  I think I may need to write a script to perform this.

Anyone have any ideas if this is possible using Ant tasks?

### Example.props

```
gameStatusCode=statusCode
gameHomeName=homeName
gameAwayName=awayName
```

### Original Source

```
if(dataitem.gameStatusCode === 'pre'){
  var tmp = dataitem.gameHomeName;
  ... 
}
```

### Replacement Source

```
if(dataitem.statusCode === 'pre'){
  var tmp = dataitem.homeName;
  ...
}
```

Comment: is this ant or nant? The question is tagged with both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`replace`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) task with `replacefilterfile` attribute:

```
<replace dir="${src}" replacefilterfile="example.props">
  <include name="**/*.java"/>
</replace>
```

Comment: Right under my nose. Not sure how I missed that. Thanks